# Blend 3 for ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight-3.0, expression-blend

I've seen [a great video](http://videos.visitmix.com/MIX09/C01F) (Mix09) of how easy it is to quickly sketch a web site using Blend 3 and specifically Sketch Flow.

What I don't dig is how to mobilize this for ASP.Net. Blend lets you "[create websites and applications based on Silverlight 3](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Blend_Features.aspx)" but how do you use Blend's output with ASP.Net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blend/SketchFlow doesn't output to an ASP.net site, it outputs XAP(silverlight) and hosts it in an HTML file and includes Silvelright.js. If you want it in the ASP.net just copy it into an ASP.net website.

However, Sketchflow doesn't support RAD prototyping of HTML/ASPX pages.

When they said creates websites based on Silverlight3, they obviously meant, you had to include Silverlight, I think that is very obvious.

If you want some tool to prototype ASPX pages, use Expression Web or Visual Studio Design View or something else, not Blend.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - it makes the issue clearer for me and confirmed my fears.
I've used Expression Web, but Blend (Sketch Flow) appears to have much better RAD capabilities. For example, it allows you to navigate the web site's pages.
It appears that I'll have to use Sketch Flow for its RAD capabilities, than manually convert to ASP.Net (as I do not want to use Silverlight. It's positioned as a Flash competitor, and I've read some articles claiming that Flash sites have usability problems).

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create the site in VS 2008 as a Silverlight, Silverlight Navigation or Silverlight Business application site. Then you can load the same site in Blend to do all the cool blend stuff to the site - build the site in Vs2008 and publish it to the web.

Comment: What I want to do is create an "ASP.Net without Silverlight" site using the "RAD" capabilities of Blend 3's Sketch Draw tool.